# SQL Server : need to find min/max/count value given time partition and conditional parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, dense-rank

I have a database containing results from horse races.

For each horse in each race i want to find their previous best time (TOTAL_TIME) given that the parameters was the same as the current race/row (DISTANCE, DIVISION, START_MODE).

I also want to count the number of times the horse won a race before the current/row date

Finally, for each race and horse; I want to RANK the competing horses based on the values calculated in 1 & 2

```
SELECT b.datum     AS RACE_DATE,/*date of race*/ 
       b.id        AS RACE_ID, 
       c.namn      AS HORSE_NAME, 
       a.plac      AS PLACEMENT,/*what position the horse finished in*/ 
       a.rank      AS RANK_ODDS, 
       a.tid       AS TOTAL_TIME,/*total time it took for horse to finish race*/ 
       b.bana      AS TRACK,/*geographical race track*/ 
       b.distans   AS DISTANCE,/*short, long, etc.*/ 
       b.division  AS DIVISION,/*what type of breed the competition was etc.*/ 
       b.startsatt AS START_MODE /*way of starting the race, car or manual*/ 
FROM   trav.prog a 
       JOIN trav.tvl b 
         ON a.tvlid = b.id 
       JOIN trav.horse c 
         ON a.horseid = c.id 
ORDER  BY race_date DESC, 
          race_id DESC
```

Sample output: (Thank you kindly for the formatting help)

```
+------------+---------+------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+----------+----------+------------+
| RACE_DATE  | RACE_ID |    HORSE_NAME    | PLACEMENT | RANK_ODDS | TOTAL_TIME | TRACK | DISTANCE | DIVISION | START_MODE |
+------------+---------+------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+----------+----------+------------+
| 2017-03-28 |  166700 | YANKEE FRECEL*   |         9 |         3 |        161 | MO    | K        | V        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166700 | ALCYONE LOVE     |         3 |         9 |        152 | MO    | K        | V        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166700 | GIANT STAR*      |         6 |         6 |        155 | MO    | K        | V        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166697 | RUBY FRONTLINE   |         6 |        11 |        188 | MO    | M        | U        | V          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166696 | CAN´T STAND STIL |         4 |         3 |        150 | MO    | K        | U        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166696 | MISS MIRCHI*     |         3 |         5 |        149 | MO    | K        | U        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166695 | LYNLINN*         |         4 |         6 |        262 | MO    | K        | U        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166695 | SIKVELANDS SVAR  |         3 |         1 |        257 | MO    | K        | U        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166692 | NOK´EN FRÆKKERT  |         1 |         6 |        134 | J     | M        | V        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166692 | FLEX LANE        |         5 |         4 |        137 | J     | M        | V        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166692 | EDWARD ALE*      |         4 |         3 |        137 | J     | M        | V        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166692 | ATTACK DIABLO    |         3 |         1 |        136 | J     | M        | V        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166692 | SOLVATO          |         2 |         2 |        136 | J     | M        | V        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166692 | CALIBER T.T.     |         7 |         8 |        140 | J     | M        | V        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166692 | KASH´S CANTAB    |         6 |         5 |        137 | J     | M        | V        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166692 | CAPELLO BOB      |         8 |         7 |        142 | J     | M        | V        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166691 | WILDINTENTION    |         4 |         2 |        125 | J     | K        | V        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166691 | MR ARKANSAS      |         3 |        10 |        124 | J     | K        | V        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166691 | KAMANDA          |         7 |         6 |        127 | J     | K        | V        | A          |
| 2017-03-28 |  166691 | APOLLO DAMGÅRD*  |         6 |         8 |        127 | J     | K        | V        | A          |
+------------+---------+------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: add your actual data and desired result.. or use sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Provide the DDL with inserts scripts for each table.